# fwrite => fprintf

Tags: c

I'm having trouble changing the line `fwrite(tmp_array, sizeof(int), num, f);` to `fprintf`.

Can someone please take a look for me?

```
 void generate_random_sorted_file(const char *file_name, int num)
 {
     FILE *f = fopen(file_name, "wb");
     if (f==NULL) 
     {
         printf("could not open %s\n", file_name);
         return;
     }

     int *tmp_array = calloc(num, sizeof(int));
     int i;

     for (i=0; i<num; i++)
     tmp_array[i]=rand();

     qsort (tmp_array, num, sizeof(int), compare); /* sorts the array */
     fwrite(tmp_array, sizeof(int), num, f);

     fclose(f);
 }
```

Comment: Need more info, what's the problem?

Comment: What kind of formatted output would you like the fprintf to provide?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: You need to state what your requirements are.  What do you want the output to be?  eg, printed to what?  looking like what? (Your code could be formatted better too)

Comment: Please stop removing the code from your question. Doing so robs us of the type information for `f`, `tmp_array`, `num` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fprintf will write the your integer array as text, if that's what you want, do something like

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
  fprintf(f,"%d ",tmp_array[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0; i<num; i++)
    fprintf(f, "%d ", tmp_array[i]);
```

If you want to format it differently you can do, but this is the bare bones.  For example, adding line breaks every 10 items:

```
for (i=0; i<num; i++)
{
    fprintf(f, "%d ", tmp_array[i]);
    if ((i+1) % 10 == 0)
        fprintf(f, "\n");
}
```

Or perhaps you want tab separators:

```
fprintf(f, "%d\t", tmp_array[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to replace fwrite(...) with

```
for(i=0; i < num; i++)  
fprintf( f, "%d", tmp_array[i] );
```

But why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to write a text file rather than a binary file? You're going to need to use a loop, something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<num; ++i)
    fprintf(f, "%d\n", tmp_array[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following for loop should solve your problem by traversing `tmp_array` and printing each value to `f`. Try using,

```
for (int i=0; i < num; i++) {
    fprintf(f, "%d\n", tmp_array[i]);
}
```